# Writing a large list of short integers with python

Tags: python-3.x, integer, struct.pack

I have a large list of values, which I want written to a file, as short integers.

I want to do this efficiently, and in Python3.

One value at a time, is possible using the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) module:

```
struct.pack( "h", val )
```

It is possible to prefix the format entry with a count, like so:

```
struct.pack( "4h", val0,val1,val2,val3 )
```

But when I try to construct the format dynamically, and write it in one go, I can't feed in a list.

For example:

```
values = [ x for x in range(100) ]
fmt = "%dh" % ( len(values), )
p = struct.pack( fmt, values )
```

Will give the error: **struct.error: pack expected 100 items for packing (got 1)**

How can I efficiently dump a large number of short integers into a file?

Basically, the Python equivalent of the C code:

```
short values[100];
fwrite( values, sizeof(values), 1, f);
```

Or am I forced to write these values one at a time if I use Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just changing one character:

```
p = struct.pack(fmt, *values)
```